# VB.NET Read .Txt File Into Multiple Text Boxes

Tags: vb.net, file, multidimensional-array

I have a program that I can enter in names and integer values in the text boxes and then save those to a file. That works perfectly fine but the part I need help with is the reading of the file.

The data is saved into the file much like a csv file. example:

```
Test, 5, 5, 5
dadea, 5, 5, 5
das, 5, 5, 5
asd, 5, 5, 5
dsadasd, 5, 5, 5
```

My problem is, how do I read that into multiple text boxes on my form?
The names (first value of each row) should go into their corresponding Name textbox (i.e. txtName0, txtName1, txtName2, etc.) and the integer values should also go into their corresponding text boxes (txtCut1, txtColour1, etc.).

I have spent the past 2 hours trying to figure this out but I just cant.

The part I need help with is the last method.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private aPricesGrid(,) As TextBox
    Private aAverages() As TextBox
    Private aNames() As TextBox

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        aPricesGrid = {{txtCut1, txtColour1, txtUpDo1, txtHighlight1, txtExtensions1},
                       {txtCut2, txtColour2, txtUpDo2, txtHighlight2, txtExtensions2},
                       {txtCut3, txtColour3, txtUpDo3, txtHighlight3, txtExtensions3},
                       {txtCut4, txtColour4, txtUpDo4, txtBHighlight4, txtExtensions4},
                       {txtCut5, txtColour5, txtUpDo5, txtHighlight5, txtExtensions5}}
        aAverages = {txtAvg0, txtAvg1, txtAvg2, txtAvg3, txtAvg4}
        aNames = {txtName0, txtName1, txtName2, txtName3, txtName4}
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        For nCol As Integer = 0 To 4
            Dim nColTotal As Integer = 0
            Dim nColItems As Integer = 0
            For nRow As Integer = 0 To 2
                Try
                    nColTotal += aPricesGrid(nRow, nCol).Text
                    nColItems += 1
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Next
            aAverages(nCol).Text = (nColTotal / nColItems).ToString("c")

        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        For Each txt As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf txt Is TextBox Then
                txt.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim oSaveFileDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        'Display the Common file Dialopg to user 
        oSaveFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        If oSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            ' Retrieve Name and open it 
            Dim fileName As String = oSaveFileDialog.FileName
            Dim outputFile As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(fileName)

            For nRow As Integer = 0 To 4
                outputFile.Write(aNames(nRow).Text)
                For nCol As Integer = 0 To 2
                    outputFile.Write(", " & aPricesGrid(nRow, nCol).Text)
                Next
                outputFile.WriteLine()
            Next
            outputFile.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReadToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim oOpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
        'Display the Common file Dialopg to user 
        oOpenFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt"

        If oOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim fileName As String = oOpenFileDialog.FileName
            Dim OpenFile As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fileName)

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method.

```
        Dim mindex as integer
        Dim string1 as string()
        Dim OpenFile As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fileName)
         While OpenFile .Peek <> -1
                string1= OpenFile .ReadLine.Split(",")
                If mindex = 0 Then
                    txtname1.text=string1(0)
                    txtcut1.text=string1(1)
                    txtcolour1.text=string1(2)
                    'add other textboxes
                ElseIf mindex = 1 Then
                    txtname2.text=string1(0)
                    txtcut2.text=string1(1)
                    txtcolour2.text=string1(2)
                    'add other textboxes
                ElseIf mindex = 2 Then
                    txtname3.text=string1(0)
                    txtcut3.text=string1(1)
                    txtcolour3.text=string1(2)
                    'add other textboxes
                ElseIf mindex = 3 Then
                  'your code
                ElseIf mindex = 4 Then
                   'your code
                End If
                mindex += 1
            End While
            OpenFile .Close()
```

hope this helps.